# Can't install pyaudio using pip

Tags: python, pygame

I tried installing pyaudio using pip but I am getting an error.

```
    C:\Users\divya>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\divya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5eoc_ykq\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xhzsi_4l\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\divya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5eoc_ykq\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xhzsi_4l\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\divya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5eoc_ykq\pyaudio\
```

please see this error and help me out I am getting similar error while installing pyGTK too. I tried upgrading pip too but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no prebuilt package for Python 3.7 on Windows (you have a 32 bit version probably) so you need to prepare build environment on your PC to use this package. Easier would be finding the wheel for 3.7 as some packages are quite hard to build on Windows.

You can find your wheel [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Check your python version and download your correct wheel

after that you can type to install:

```
pip install <yourwheel.whl>
```